# Minimizing mixed-norm subject to a nonconvex quartic constraint for small n and m

Tags: optimization, qcqp

How can one solve this mixed-norm minimization problem subject to a quartic constraint for small N and M (ex: M=12 and N=4):

- $\textbf{c} = [c_{1},...,c_{N}]^T$
- $min\biggl (\|\textbf{c}\|_{1} + \beta\|\textbf{c}\|_{2} ^2\biggr) subject\space
     to\space \sum\limits_ {m=1} ^M (|v_ {m} |^2-\textbf{c}^H\textbf{a}_m\textbf{a}_m^H\textbf{c})
     ^2\leq\epsilon$

Thank you for advance for any suggestions.

Comment: This is not a convex problem, so you should remove that tag

Comment: ...and it is not a quadratic constraint, it is quartic

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The problem is taken from this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8328805) and there they mention that it is quadratic.

Comment: Well that is obviously incorrect as you have a square of a quadratic. What they do is that they write the nonconvex quartic model as a rank-constrained (thus non-convex) semidefinite program with a convex quadratic constraint.